# How to get the previous day value as a measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

**Situation:**

I currently have two columns (date, value). I would like to create a measure calculating the previous day value.

**Sample values:**

```
date    Column1
1/1/2019 0:00   10
1/2/2019 0:00   20
1/3/2019 0:00   30
1/4/2019 0:00   50
1/5/2019 0:00   100
1/6/2019 0:00   20
1/7/2019 0:00   30
1/8/2019 0:00   40
```

**Sample Output:**

```
+---------------+---------+---------------+
|     date      | Column1 | previousvalue |
+---------------+---------+---------------+
| 1/1/2019 0:00 |      10 |               |
| 1/2/2019 0:00 |      20 |            10 |
| 1/3/2019 0:00 |      30 |            20 |
| 1/4/2019 0:00 |      50 |            30 |
| 1/5/2019 0:00 |     100 |            50 |
| 1/6/2019 0:00 |      20 |           100 |
| 1/7/2019 0:00 |      30 |            20 |
| 1/8/2019 0:00 |      40 |            30 |
+---------------+---------+---------------+
```

Comment: can you share your dax code of what have you tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `PREVIOUSDAY` function in your filter expression in the `CALCULATE` method

```
PreviousValue = 
CALCULATE(
 SUMX(example,example[Column1]),
 PREVIOUSDAY(example[date])
)
```